Issue with changing name of my heroku app in heroku cli
I can't change name of my heroku app from heroku cli:
(ll_env) [arch@archlinux dj_proj]$ heroku apps:rename my_learning_log
 ›   ModuleLoadError: [MODULE_NOT_FOUND] require failed to load 
 ›   /usr/lib/heroku/lib/commands/apps/rename.js: Cannot find module 'tmp'
 ›   Require stack:
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/lib/lib/ci/git.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/lib/commands/apps/rename.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/module-loader.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/help/util.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/help/formatter.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/help/command.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/help/index.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/flags.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/styled/table.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/styled/index.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/command.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/index.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/command.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/index.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/lib/global_telemetry.js
 ›   - /usr/lib/heroku/bin/run
 ›   Code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND

I also tried change the name of the new name, but it didn't work.

First ensure that django-heroku is installed in your active virtual environment. Use pip list in your active virtual environment to check whether django-heroku is installed.
Assuming you're logged into Heroku (verify by running heroku whoami), To rename your app, run the heroku apps:rename command from your app’s Git repository.
heroku apps:rename new-example-app

You can also rename an app from outside of its associated Git repository by including the --app option in the command.
heroku apps:rename newname --app oldname

You can also rename an app from the dashboard by clicking the name of the app and then the Settings tab.
Note that when you rename an app, it’s immediately available at the new corresponding herokuapp.com subdomain, and it’s unavailable at the old one. See Renaming Apps.

I definitely installed heroku and login to account, output from 'heroku apps:rename newname --app oldname' the same.

Can you rename through dashboard?
